# Ext js overriding a config property

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a ext-js component definition like below..

```
Ext.define("Demo.widgets.nav", {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
  xtype: 'nav',
  id:'nav',
  requires: ['Ext.dataview.List'],

     config : {
        autoHide: false,
        maxWidth: 265,
        lastSelect:null,
        itemSelection:null,
           .
           .
           ...
     }
```

Basically this component was defined in one of our custom framework which we use it as a platform to build the application. We don't have any control on it.  We found a bug in one of the config property "autoHide". It should be true but defined as false in it.

I am trying override that component to change that config property like below.

```
Ext.define( 'demo.widgets.nav', {
override: 'demo.widgets.nav',
   config : {
     autoHide: true
   }
});
```

while overriding, Is it just enough to mention the property we need or do we need to copy all the properties of config in the original component.

Till now I did overwrite only the functions for which I either copy whole function source with modifications or use callOverridden() to call original function.

I just confused in overwriting the config properties.

Comment: So, what is your question? You can change when you create a new instance of this control or you can override it as you did.

Comment: I m asking is it correct way to override config properties

Comment: Yes they should get merged with the original classes config options, overwriting any that match with the override's value.